# PostgreSQL multilevel search in JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, multi-level

The question is how to search (using `LIKE` statement) in multilevel JSON column in PostgreSQL.

I want to search by `name`, which is in the `en` or in any another language which is supported by column.

Table:

[image: table example]

```html
places
-------

id                     ascii_name                    translations

dsrsfdsf               be-namor      { "en":{"locale":"en","name":"Namur"},"de":{"locale":"de","name":"Namur"},"bg":{"locale":"bg","name":"Намюр"} }
s3drs2es        be-mouscron          { "en":{"locale":"en","name":"Mouscron"},"pl":{"locale":"pl","name":"Mouscron"},"de":{"locale":"de","name":"Mouscron"} }
```

I've just found a way using json_object_keys, but it causes an error that I can't use set-returning function in WHERE statement.

```
SELECT * FROM places p WHERE p.translations->json_object_keys(p.translations)->'name' LIKE '%Namur%'
```

Error:

> [0A000] ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
so=# with c(j) as (values
 ('{ "en":{"locale":"en","name":"Namur"},"de":{"locale":"de","name":"Namur"},"bg":{"locale":"bg","name":"Намюр"} }'::json)
,('{ "en":{"locale":"en","name":"Mouscron"},"pl":{"locale":"pl","name":"Mouscron"},"de":{"locale":"de","name":"Mouscron"} }')
)
, filter as (select j,j->json_object_keys(j)->>'name' like '%amur%' as "found" from c)
select distinct j::jsonb from filter where found;
                                                              j
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"bg": {"name": "Намюр", "locale": "bg"}, "de": {"name": "Namur", "locale": "de"}, "en": {"name": "Namur", "locale": "en"}}
(1 row)
```

mind I cast json to jsonb to filter out dupes